# jQuery plugin becomes undefined when called from within $.get

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery TokenInput and there's a place in my code where I'd like to do an Ajax call prior to actually calling TokenInput. However, if I try to call TokenInput from within `$.get` I get

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tokenInput'`

So this works:

```
$("#myfield").tokenInput('/search/', {
    tokenLimit: 3
});
$("#myfield").tokenInput("add", { id: 100, name: "Fake Data" });
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var old_value = $("#myfield").val();
$("#myfield").tokenInput('/search/', {
    tokenLimit: 3
});
$.get('/search/', { q: old_value }, function (data) {
    record = data[0];
    $("#myfield").tokenInput("add", {id: record.id, name: record.name });
});
```

So I guess what I'm wondering is, what happened to `$.tokenInput`? Is there something I can do to ensure it's available from within `$.get`?

**Source code for jQuery.TokenInput: https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js**

## Update

Oh *horsefeathers*. Looking at the code I see that another section of code (in this case, from django-cms) is pulling in a different version of jQuery. This is **not** as a result of my `$.get` request, it's just on another part of the page.

Here's what I don't get, though: why does it work in one context but not the other? Both jQuery versions are already loaded by the time we get to the `$.tokenInput` code. So what is happening to `$` so that it retains `.tokenInput`?

Also, I thought that there was a way to have two versions of jQuery on a single page and not  run into problems -- that one version of jQuery will somehow "preserve" the other version. Obviously it's able to do it partially, since $.tokenInput does work *some* of the time.

Fortunately on *this* page I was able to just disable the module that calls the other jQuery, but I won't always be able to. What steps can I take to deal with this situation, given that I **cannot** avoid having two versions on the page? (django-cms is only compatible with an older version of jQuery. Very annoying, but nothing I can do about it).

Comment: can you put here the code for the plugin?

Comment: @Martin edited my question to add source to plugin.

Comment: I assume you are showing us pseudo-code and not actual code.  Is your actual `$.get()` success method appending anything from the server to the DOM before attempting to use `$.fn.tokenInput `? If so, I would guess that a script tag with src of jQuery is in the returned markup which you're appending, causing jQuery to be redefined when it is appended thereby losing all additions to jQuery which had been in place.

Comment: @JAAulde **"The variable names have been changed but the code is real"**. It's not pseudo-code. Literally all I'm doing is retrieving a value from the server and then calling `.tokenInput`.

Comment: @JAAulde You were right in suspecting there was another instance of jQuery... however it's already loaded on the page by the time we get to the `$.tokenInput` code. Any ideas on why it would work sometimes but not always?

Comment: @JordanReiter heh, I figured it had to be something like that--I've been there! I'd have to see the page to be sure, but I suspect the script blocks where it is working are above the script element which loads in the second copy. So they run just fine--until you drop something into an async method like an AJAX call back--by the time it fires, the later script blocks have executed, removing the support needed in the callback.

Comment: I've gone through the exact same problem, in which my jQuery plugins were undefined in AJAX callbacks.  Turns out my MVC layout template contained a **second** reference to jquery.js at the end of the page.  Looks like the second time jQuery was loaded, it wiped out all plugins.  So depending on context/location, plugins would either be defined or not.  Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

### Relative to the problem.

*This is not a direct anwser to the question, but general fact about killing jQuery plugins. I've had a problem as described below and after googling it I ended up here, so maybe someone will too.*

Appending `<script />` tags to the `document` will execute these scripts and possibly kill all your plugins inside `$`.

Harmful script:

```
// Here html response has full index.php body,
// i.e. html has <body /> and <script /> tags inside
// (including `<script src="js/jquery.js">`).
$.get(url).done(function(html)
{
    // Here happens redeclaration of jQuery variable (i.e. $ variable),
    // because of `<script src="js/jquery.js">` inside `<body />`.
    // 
    // Redeclaration of jQuery variable mean
    // that all plugins will die (i.e. all
    // not native jQuery attributes become undefined).
    $(html).appendTo("body");
});
```

edit:

Another example:

```
$("<html />").html("<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>");
```

will load `jquery.js`.

Thing to note: scripts injected like this will be loaded via ajax  (i.e. `XMLHttpRequest`).

Note: all of this was tested in Chrome, but jQuery behaviour regarding html parsing is **not** cross-browser:

*"When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. **During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements.** As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed."*

[source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the script blocks in which it is working are above the script element which loads in the second copy. So they run just fine--until you drop something into an async method like an AJAX call back. By the time that fires, the later script blocks have executed, removing the support needed in the callback

See example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RukeN/1/

Comment: The `jquery.tokeninput.js` file is loaded after *everything else*, followed by my code. So new jQuery loads, followed by old, bad jQuery, followed by TokenInput, followed by my code. Still, I'm intrigued by the idea of it having to do with the async delay...